# When is the "tweet this" button visible?

Tags: support, twitter

My question is simple and short. When exactly is the "tweet this" button visible for a given answer?

For example when I go to a question I answered [Duplicate type error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447879/duplicate-type-error/8447976#8447976) I don't see the "tweet this" button. I know for sure it's visible directly after I gave the answer.

Comment: Is that functionality ever available on answers?  I thought it was only on questions.  Do you have an example of an answer with it?

Comment: @David Yes I have used it multiple times. Well I can't give you a example because they aren't visible now hence the question. I guess they are only visible directly after answering? I now also notice that the tweet this button for this question is also missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeff answers this question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80880/please-ditch-all-of-the-share-icons-they-give-me-nightmares/80910#80910):

> This only appears:
>
> - a random percent of the time, decreasing chance with greater reputation- on your posts
> - if they are greater than 400 characters in length
> - for 1 hour after posting

Note: The other question (where Jeff posted his answer) is not a dupe of this one, since it was a request to "please-ditch-all-of-the-share-icons-they-give-me-nightmares"

Comment: @jardarnal27 Thanks. Well I can empathize with people who don't like it but there are enough people like me who don't care and ask them self where is that button. I've seen it before? A better implementation would be to leave it to the user. If you don't like it disable it or the other way around.

Comment: I wouldn't want to Tweet everything anyway, but on the odd occasion that it does pop up it gets me thinking "Hmm, in fact, do I?" - and, rarely, but still, I do. I think it's worth it.

Comment: @MartijnB I don't really understand why people get so upset about the buttons to be honest =)  In case you did not notice, the "share" buttons are always there on the question (right below the voting buttons).

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment That would make for a rather controversial [feature-request], wouldn't it?  (To always show the sharing buttons)

Comment: @jadarnel27 Oh, I wouldn't want that! And I don't think I implied as much?

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment Haha, I think I mis-read your comment.  My mistake =)

Comment: I am going to give it some more thoughts and maybe start a discussion for a feature request.

Comment: Discussion started - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116002/more-control-on-share-buttons-on-answers