# What controls the visibility of the "Share your answer" section?

Tags: support, answers, share-this

As the title states, I've noticed that after answering a question I can share my answer on Facebook/Twitter, yet this option disappears when looking at answers I've posted previously elsewhere.

Is there a way to access these links when revisiting a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Jeff has said the popup is random.  You can get it anytime you like using the "link" link just under the tags, next to edit, close, flag, etc.

Edit:
Or did you mean this one: [Please ditch all of the share icons - they give me nightmares](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80880/172958)?  If so, see that post for Jeff's answer.

Comment: Ha ha ha, trust a coder to throw a random modifier in there.