# But I don't wanna share

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, answers, share-this

For some reason on my [newest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11103825/561731) I have a box on the bottom asking me to share my answer on random social networks:

[image]

**None** of my other answers have that little box....

How long does it stay there, and **why** is it there?

---

This happens on all new answers. It does **not** seem to be random....

Comment: Dupe of [What controls the visibility of the "Share your answer" section?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118102) nes-pas?

Comment: Jeff describes what controls those here: [Please ditch all of the share icons - they give me nightmares](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80880/please-ditch-all-of-the-share-icons-they-give-me-nightmares/80910#80910)

Comment: +1, I thought the same multiple times.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i do not have the same results, the box doesn't disappear when I look elsewhere.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: It does disappear, usually, eventually.

Comment: @MartijnPieters sometimes, maybe? ^_^

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Give it a few hours.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: "for 1 hour after posting", Jeff sez: [Please ditch all of the share icons - they give me nightmares](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80880)

Comment: If you don't want to share, you don't have to :-)

Comment: @martjin _n'est-ce pas_ . _nes_ isn't a word, _n'est-ce pas?_

Comment: Do you use a tablet pen? That's impressive if it's a mouse drawn circle

Comment: @BenBrocka I **do not** use a tablet pen, I am at my office on a Dell Precision T3500 with a mouse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We're experimenting with tweaking the rules on showing the share buttons.

New rules are the [old rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80880/please-ditch-all-of-the-share-icons-they-give-me-nightmares), but without the length and random constraints.

I honestly expect this to do nothing to their usage*, and if the number bears this out we'll be pulling them**.

<sub>*Which is abysmal.</sub>

<sub>**Though I may have to crack some heads to get that done.</sub>

Comment: Now that Rebecca's hands are safely on the keyboard typing out bug fixes, you can steal her contractually-dulled-but-still-menacing stick to threaten anyone who gives you trouble.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA well, you just added the [tag:bug] tag...

Comment: @KevinMontrose I never really realized it was a total bug until I saw your update to the post explaining when we get the share icons.

Comment: I don't use them because I don't like patting myself on the back. Now, if they showed up randomly under highly upvoted (accepted?) answers, I might share _other people's answers_ more readily.

Comment: @jcolebrand yea, but it only seems to show up on **your own answers** and only for **you** and only for the first hour (and only....)

Comment: Won't this increase the number of users who are sick of them, instead of increasing the number of users who use them?

Comment: @Toomai Probably.  And believe me I'd rather they were gone.  This is gathering data to make the argument that nobody uses them for good reason, the random and length constraints made it hard to build a convincing argument.  You can think of this is lifting the Science Hammer in preparation for dropping it.

Comment: Hey Neal, that's my POINT. I'm trying to offer an alternative to Kevin.

Comment: @Kevin, I really wish you would approach the team about changing the mentality from "show my answers" to "help me evangelize the network more easily" because there are some of these that I would evangelize, but very very few of my own.

Comment: @jcolebrand analytics show us that a great many of posts are *shared*, but nobody uses the share buttons to do so.  Note that we always show the question share buttons to everyone, always, and they also get garbage usage.  Looks like people would much rather copy/paste links than use those buttons, no matter what the display rules are.  This change is testing that hypothesis.

Comment: Wait, so there's been a method in the past to share an answer that wasn't mine? I feel like this conversation would be so much smoother over chat, because I think we're talking across each other. I want to share the occasional Skeet answer on twitter, because it blows my mind. I don't currently have a button to share a skeet answer, so I have to use the link. When Skeet asks a question, I can tweet _that_, because it has a button. Where's the button for me to share Skeet's answer?

Comment: @jcolebrand I'd assume people are just copy+pasting the referral links from the "link" link.

Comment: @jcolebrand there is no button, you copy paste the URL (or the link in the ["link" menu item](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sJW4M.png) ); analytics show thus far that people are much more willing to do *that* than use the share buttons.

Comment: 'abysmal' I stopped trying to use those links because they showed up like 1% of the time...just shared the question instead

Comment: So this question and its similars should be [status-planned] then? :P

Comment: @Toomai - [tag:status-god-willing] really.

Comment: @KevinMontrose so can we _add that feature_ to an answer? That's what I'm asking. I want that to be internally discussed, it does us no good. Shall I make it formal with a Q?

Comment: @jcolebrand I'm not really sure what you're proposing.  We're unlikely to make changes to sharing stuff while trying this change out.  You're welcome to post a question naturally.

Comment: I'll do that to cement it and make it clearer...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136760/invert-the-sharing-feature-for-answers-from-the-current-model

Comment: http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/730/can-we-still-twitter-our-answers-out @KevinMontrose see users wanting it.

Comment: @jcolebrand it seems all the share links on questions are gone now :-(

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA yes, that's why I linked to my meta where my users want to see it.