# Share icons appearing on every post

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, share-this

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [But I don't wanna share](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136720/but-i-dont-wanna-share)

The share icons appear to have started appearing on *every* answer, starting  today (June 19th).  According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80910) they should only appear "a random percent of the time, decreasing chance with greater reputation".  Given my StackOverflow reputation, I would not expect to see this repeatedly for every post in a day.  Is this a bug?

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: Are you saying you're experiencing the same problem with the share widget appearing on every new post you make? Or just one of them?

Comment: I think this is different - I understand wanting to ignore it, but this is happening on every post for me today.  The behavior has changed as far as I can tell.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn same issue. See Kevin's update on my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sharing button rules changed last night as part of an experiment, I missed updating the meta post; my bad.

New rules are the same as the [old ones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80880/please-ditch-all-of-the-share-icons-they-give-me-nightmares), but without the length and random requirements.

If (and I fully expect, when) this change does nothing to their usage we'll be reverting/pulling them.

So uh, I guess continue treating them with the disdain they deserve.

Comment: "Without the random requirements" - Does that mean it's basically going to always be on every post until this is pulled?

Comment: @ReedCopsey that is what it seems... :-(

Comment: @Reed - for the first hour of its existence, yes.  Unless the question is closed.

Comment: When making controversial changes like this, you guys might want to think about adding a stackapp to turn them off.

Comment: Okay - just know that I despise this ;) and I suspect a lot of other poeple will too

Comment: @Wont - frankly I want these buttons gone, more documentation of "our users dislike this, duh!" is an OK outcome in that pursuit.

Comment: @Reed I despise them too, counting the days till the experiment ends.

Comment: @KevinMontrose Yeah - way too aggressive and too many wasted pixels

Comment: @KevinMontrose - Can we have a countdown somewhere to experiment end?

Comment: The experiment is over and all I can say is, Thank You!