# Where did the sharing buttons (twitter/G+ etc) go?

Tags: support, share-this

I have searched here and using Google and cannot find any guidance on this.

I have an old question I just added a bounty to and I don't see any options for publicizing it:

[What is the purpose of System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.IsNullable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821850/what-is-the-purpose-of-system-data-sqlclient-sqlparameter-isnullable/)

Comment: Odd, I hadn't even noticed that the sharing buttons had disappeared... I can only get the sentence above the answer box to appear on questions with no answers.

Comment: you might consider supporting http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136760/invert-the-sharing-feature-for-answers-from-the-current-model

Answer (score 18):

Canada.

But really, [they were removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80880/please-ditch-all-of-the-share-icons-they-give-me-nightmares) entirely just recently because their usage rate was apparently way too low.

[Kevin Montrose](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130213/kevin-montrose) (SE developer) wrote about the change [on his personal blog](http://kevinmontrose.com/2012/06/20/are-you-measuring-your-social-media-buttons/).

On July 23, 2012, they were [added back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136760/add-social-media-sharing-icons-to-the-link-popup/140905#140905) as a part of the "share" (formerly the "link") pop-up.

Comment: And people hated them. With the power of 10,000 suns.

Comment: Oh come now @Rosinante, *my* hatred was at *least* an order of magnitude higher.  Anyway, I'm glad they're gone; they really messed up the flow of reading a question you had answered.

Comment: I can understand these complaints about the box that appear in between answers, but how do the ones below the question's vote counter irritate people?

Comment: Fi-nah-lee! @animuson: I can't really explain *how*, but all the buttons and links irritated me enough to learn how to write Chrome extensions.

Comment: -1; I looked all over Canada and they're not here!