# Can we have a mail-it option in share?

Tags: feature-request, share-this

Currently we have only three options ie Twitter, Facebook and Google+. It will be great to have a mail-it option there. Sometimes I discuss some issue with my friends and while browsing on Stackoverflow on my iPad or Mac or iPhone, I see the same issue discussed on Stackoverflow or some nice post I check on Stackoverflow and I want to share it with friend.

Now in order to send it via email, I want have to copy the title the question in subject or manually type the subject and in content I specify mail is just URL of that Post. It will great by pressing a icon most of the things are pre filled and I just type friend's email and its done :)

PS: Heights of lazzines, but it will good to have this thing :)

[image]

Comment: Why not just tweet it? If your friend follows you, surely he/she will see it, no?  Plus, you'd be doing the question a great service by getting the word out to others as well. The main thing these 3 buttons have that email doesn't is that they're designed to reach lots of people; they're designed to scale.

Comment: @jmort253 I am from India and my friends (in my country, every one) don't use or check twitter regularly. And I am talking about a user friendly thing.

Comment: Facebook? Google Plus? Really? I have colleagues in India I work with, and they use Facebook and G+ more than I do. :)

Comment: @jmort253 You said twitter.. Thats why I said that.. I dont want to spoil every1s thing.. All my friends will see oh Mohit posted stackoverflow link on Jmort profile. I just want to tell that person to check a link.. not to whole list of my followers or friends. Every1 is not interested in that. That issue is specific to a user not to a public.

Comment: @jmort253 Take a look on this http://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/screen-shot-2012-07-31-at-13-06-06.png?w=631&h=483

Comment: If you get your friends on Twitter, then a tweet still reaches more people than a single email. Just because tweets in India are 10% lower than the global average doesn't mean they reach less people than a single email will. Numbers are cool and all, but sometimes they measure the wrong thing. ;)

Comment: U took me wrong. My point was in india people don't use twitter that much.. :)

Comment: Hi Mohit, I get that, but a single Tweet from you will still reach more people than a single email to your 1 friend. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know, I was going to write up an answer describing why this wouldn't be a benefit but then stopped. As it stands, it took a lot of coaxing to convince the Stack Exchange developers to [please add back the social networking links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140190/155826). Reluctantly, they did. But I think the feature still might be on probation, so the more we use it, the better!

I found the original user script from Manishearth:  [Add "Share" Buttons to the Link Popup](https://stackapps.com/q/3514/4812), which is sort of the template for the current share box.

It shouldn't be hard to expose that email link, especially since the code is right there in the user script. However, the developers generally won't implement things that don't scale.

So, for now, you could use the user script as a temporary hack. I had the user script installed for awhile right after the feature was released, and you do see 2 popups, so it's not perfect, but it may be easier for you than copy and pasting manually, and it may be your only option as I'm not sure Stack Exchange would implement this just to send out 1 link. Hope this helps!

As an aside, I was also thinking someone could modify the user script to just add the email functionality to the existing new popup.

Comment: I already have that thing. But will not work on my iPhone or iPad :( Anyways thanks a lot.

Comment: How about GreasePocket? http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/greasepocket_greasemonkey_for.php

Comment: Seems promising. Lemme check. Once again thanks a lot :)