# Facebook Like on SO answers

Tags: support, answers, facebook

For the first time, or at least the first time that I noticed, an answer I authored on SO had a "Like this on Facebook" option.  I didn't click it, but later I decided I'd give it a try (besides, I had a great answer).  When I went back to my answer, the option to "Like on Facebook" disappeared.

What is the story with this?  :)

Comment: To clarify, it does _not_ say "like this on Facebook", it asks if you want to share it. Although similar, "liking" and "sharing" are distinct actions, and behave differently. Unless they've implemented something new, it never asks you to click "Like", just asks whether you'd like to share with friends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jeff [has explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80910/162705) that this appears

> - a random percent of the time, decreasing chance with greater reputation
> - on your posts
> - if they are greater than 400 characters in length
> - for 1 hour after posting

Comment: What he doesn't explain, is why the first and fourth criteria exist at all.

Comment: @BrentArias True. I imagine that the button is a small concession to the social networks, but note that a number of people wish that the Facebook and Twitter buttons never appeared *at all*.