# Who/what/when/where/how/why can I share my answers?

Tags: support, answers, sharing

I've notice that sometimes I can tweet my SO answers.

Something like [image: this]

shows up by my answer.

- **Who** se answers can I share?
- <s>**What** was I thinking when I decided that the who/what/when... theme was a good idea?</s>
- **When** does this happen?  It looks like I can only share my answer for a short time after I post it.
- <s>**Where** do the tweets/shares go in the series of pipes and tubes?</s>
- <s>**How** lame is this bullet point?</s>
- **Why** does this happen?  Does the answer have to get upvotes?  Are all answers share-able?

Comment: Some weird / complicated reasons here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80880/please-ditch-all-of-the-share-icons-they-give-me-nightmares/80910#80910

Answer (score 14):

This only appears:

- a random percent of the time, decreasing chance with greater reputation
- on your posts
- if they are greater than 400 characters in length
- for 1 hour after posting

Comment: "decreasing chance with greater reputation" I love little details like this.